# "Rich Text Box" form field stop working in production

Tags: php, laravel, richtextbox, voyager

Hey i am using Laravel Voyager Admin Panel for my website.

all things are working good in localmachine but when i deployed my website in production my admin panel form fiels "Rich Text Box" stop working

[richtext box not visible](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nEsJZ.png)

anyhow my richtextbox starts working

Comment: It requires javascript. Check the console log in the browser what errors it shows. [edit] your question then and add more details, as right now it is not really clear what you're asking about, it's more you're telling us that you started with troubleshooting but didn't go far yet. What always can help in such situations is that you share _your_ current understanding of the error picture. That normally allows others to give better feedback and sometimes even in the end it may reveal an answer.